# Convert Excel .xlsx to list of vectors in R

Tags: r, excel, list

After importing a .xlsx file into R (readxl package), how could I make a list of vector out of it (the first column as the vector name)?

Example .xlsx input (note that it has a variable number of columns per row):

```
row_1 | A | B |
row_2 | C | D | E |
row_3 | F | G | H | I |
```

Output I am trying to obtain:

```
$`row_1`
[1] "A" "B"

$`row_2` 
[1] "C" "D" "E" 

$`row_3`
[1] "F" "G" "H" "I"
```

My attempt so far:

```
xcel <- read_excel("my_data.xlsx", col_names=F)
df <- scan(xcel)
```

I tried different flavours of this command lines but end up either with 'Error in file(file, "r") : invalid 'description' argument' or 'Error in scan(xcel) : 'file' must be a character string or connection', depending if I convert 'xcel' as a data frame or not.

Comment: What do you mean by "without success". Is there an error? A warning? Are values missing? Does it seem like it just needs a little data wrangling to get into your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `na.omit` on the return value of `read_excel` to get what you want:

```
xcel <- read_excel("my_data.xlsx", col_names=FALSE)
xl <- apply(xcel,1,function(r)as.vector(na.omit(r))[-1])
names(xl) <- xcel[[1]]
```

`xl` looks like:

```
$row_1
[1] "A" "B"

$row_2
[1] "C" "D" "E"

$row_3
[1] "F" "G" "H" "I"
```

Comment: The vector name must be the first column of the excel file as in the given example though

Comment: @user31888 The edited code will now use the strings in the first column as names for the vectors in the list. It is actually easier than my original code since it doesn't need to use `paste` to create the names.

Comment: Awesome ! Thanks John !